# Hide form once validation is true

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to hide my form, once all the validation is correct

```
   window.addEventListener('load', init)

function init(e)
{

    var firstName = document.querySelector('#first-name');
    var lastName = document.querySelector('#last-name');
    var email = document.querySelector('#email');
    var emailConfirm = document.querySelector('#email-confirm');
    var phoneNumber = document.querySelector('#phone');
    var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    var span = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    var label = document.querySelectorAll('label');
    var fields = document.querySelectorAll("#form input[type=text]");
    var form = document.querySelector('#form');


    submit.addEventListener('click', Edit);
    submit.addEventListener('click', Results);

    function Edit(e)
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        {
            if (fields[i].value=="")
            {
                span[i].innerHTML = "*";
                span[i].style.color = "red"
                label[i].style.color = "red";
            }
            else
            {
                span[i].innerHTML="";
                label[i].style.color = "black";
            }
        }

        if (email.value !== emailConfirm.value)
            {
                span[2].innerHTML = "Emails do not match";
                span[3].innerHTML = "Emails do not match"
            }
            else
            {
                span[2].innerHTML = "";
                span[3].innerHTML = "";
            }
    }
```

So once all field are filled in and once the email and email confirmation match i need the form to hide once submit is clicked, and then display a conformation page

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have access to your form element in your JS Code

```
 var form = document.querySelector('#form');
```

All you have to do is

```
 form.style.display = 'none';
```

to hide it.

Comment: But that hides the form even if all the validation isn't true. I need the form to hide ONLY if all the Edit() function is true.

Comment: I have something like.... `    function Results(e)
    {
        if(Edit() === true)
        {
            form.style.display = 'hidden';
        }
        else
        {
            form.style.display = 'visible';
        }
    }`

Comment: Try to change 'hidden' to 'none' and 'visible' to 'block'.

Comment: If the Edit() function is the one you posted above, it doesn't return a value (which means it will return undefined). So Edit() will never be true.

Comment: You will have to modify your function so it will return true if all fields contain the desired values and return false otherwise.

Comment: No. However, you can for example declare a variable "isValid" at the top of your function and initialize it to "true". Then you validate every field and if any of the validations fail you set it to "false". At the end of the function you return your "isValid" variable.

Comment: Perfect it worked! Now if i want to display a confirmaiton field once the form hides would i just add .. confirmaiton.style.display = 'visbily'; under the form.style.display = 'none';

Comment: There is no value of "visible" or "visibly" for the CSS "display" property. If your confirmation field is a div or another block level HTML element, then use confirmation.style.display = 'block'

Comment: Ok perfect, and if i wanted all the information that was filled in on the form to display on the confirmation page would i just add the field.value to the info <p> tag in the confirmation section

Comment: Yes you could do that.